# Python datetime module and timedelta methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, date, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime as dt


fmt = '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
for i in range(int(input())):
    print(int(abs((dt.strptime(input(), fmt) - 
                   dt.strptime(input(), fmt)).total_seconds())))
```

Why are we able to call the `total_seconds()` method without importing the `timedelta` class? As `total_seconds()` is a method in `timedelta` class.

Comment: the module datetime imports it for its own use. you may import a module when you need o instanciate a class from it or call a static mehod from it

Answer (score 1):

When you subtract 2 datetime objects, the result is timedelta object.

```
from datetime import datetime

dt1 = datetime.now()
dt2 = datetime.now()

value = dt2 - dt1

print(type(value))
```

Output is:

```
<class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, as you are subtracting two `datetime` objects. As per the method `__sub__` it returns `timedelta` object (See below). And as you said `total_seconds` is method of `timedelta` class.

```
    def __sub__(self, other):
        "Subtract two datetimes, or a datetime and a timedelta."
        if not isinstance(other, datetime):
            if isinstance(other, timedelta):
                return self + -other
            return NotImplemented

        days1 = self.toordinal()
        days2 = other.toordinal()
        secs1 = self._second + self._minute * 60 + self._hour * 3600
        secs2 = other._second + other._minute * 60 + other._hour * 3600
        base = timedelta(days1 - days2,
                         secs1 - secs2,
                         self._microsecond - other._microsecond)
        if self._tzinfo is other._tzinfo:
            return base
        myoff = self.utcoffset()
        otoff = other.utcoffset()
        if myoff == otoff:
            return base
        if myoff is None or otoff is None:
            raise TypeError("cannot mix naive and timezone-aware time")
        return base + otoff - myoff
```

Answer (score 0):

The import machinery works at 2 levels. First it loads and execute the module. So if it contains other imports, they are loaded (and executed) too. That means that the instruction

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

actually loads `datetime` (to be able to access `datetime.datetime`), and `datetime.datetime`. Because of that, `datetime.timedelta` is loaded too. In fact, it is required from `datetime.datetime` to be able to define the difference between 2 `datetime.datetime` objects. So everything has been loaded by the Python interpretor.

The second level imports *symbols* in the current namespace. At this level,

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

only creates the `dt` symbol in the namespace. That means that if you use directly `datetime` in your code, you will get a `NameError` because the symbol is undefined, but if you examine `sys.module`, you will find that it is there...